# Find index of Nth occurrence of a number using Binary Search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have a finite array whose elements are only -1,0 or 1. I want to find the index of Nth occurrence of a number (say 0).

I can iterate through the entire array, but I'm looking for a faster approach. I can think of using Binary Search, but having trouble modelling the algorithm. How do I proceed with Binary Search in this case?

Comment: If you have an array, you can't do a binary search.  If you turn your array into a binary tree, you can certainly perform your search, but the order of the tree will not necessarily match the order of your array.

Comment: Are we to assume that the array is sorted?

Comment: The array is unsorted

Comment: Then a binary search does you no good. A binary search assumes that the array is sorted.

Comment: Are you able to sort your data, or does it have to maintain its ordered structure?

Comment: The ordered structure is important

Answer (score 10):

You cannot do this without at least one pass of **O(N)** pre-processing.  From an standpoint of information theory alone, you *must* have knowledge of elements [0:k-1] to know whether element [k] is the one you want.

If you're going to make this search many times, then you can make a simple linear pass over the array, counting each element as you go.  Store the indices in a 2-D array, so you can directly index whatever occurrence you want.

For instance, given [-1 0 1 1 -1 -1 0 0 0 -1 1], you can convert this to a 3xN array, idx

```
[[0 4 5 9]]
[[1 6 7 8]]
[[2 3 10]]
```

The Nth occurrence of element I is `idx[I+1][N-1]`.

After that initial O(N) pass, your look-up is O(1) time, using O(N) space.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you are looking to search through an `array`, a `vector` or some `container` where the search in question pertains to the index location of some element `T` based on its `Nth` occurrence within its container this post may be of some help to you:*

---

According to your question as well as some of the comments in regards to it where you explicitly stated that your container is `Unsorted` while you were thinking of using a `binary search` and were having trouble with the process of modeling an algorithm:

- This post here serves as an example of the development process towards the design of an algorithm in which it may help you achieve what you are looking for:
- The search algorithm here is a linear one, where a binary search will not be suitable to your current needs:
- This same process of building an algorithm can be applied to other types of algorithms including, binary searches, hash tables, etc.

---

**- 1st Build**

```
struct Index {
    static unsigned counter; // Static Counter

    unsigned location; // index location of Nth element
    unsigned count; // How many of this element up to this point

    Index() : location( 0 ), count( 0 ) {}
};    
unsigned Index::counter = 0;

// These typedefs are not necessarily needed; 
// just used to make reading of code easier.
typedef Index IndexZero; 
typedef Index IndexPos1;
typedef Index IndexNeg1;

template<class T>
class RepititionSearch {
public:
    // Some Constants to compare against: don't like "magic numbers"
    const T NEG { -1 }; 
    const T ZERO { 0 };
    const T POS { 1 };

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;   // The actual array or vector of data to be searched
    std::vector<Index> indices_; // A vector of Indexes - record keeping to prevent multiple full searches.

public:
    // Instantiating a search object requires an already populated container
    explicit RepititionSearch ( const std::vector<T>& data ) : data_( data )  {
        // make sure indices_ is empty upon construction.
        indices_.clear();
    }

    // method to find the Nth occurrence of object A
    unsigned getNthOccurrence( unsigned NthOccurrence, T element ) {
        // Simple bounds checking
        if ( NthOccurrence < 0 || NthOccurrence >= data.size() ) {
            // Can throw error or print message...;
            return -1;
        }           

        IndexZero zeros;
        IndexPos1 ones;
        IndexNeg1 negOnes;

        // Clear out the indices_ so that each consecutive call is correct
        indices_.clear();
        unsigned idx = 0;
        for ( auto e : data_ ) {
            if (  element == e && element == NEG ) {
                ++negOnes.counter;
                negOnes.location = idx;
                negOnes.count = negOnes.counter;
                indices_.push_back( negOnes );
            }

            if ( element == e && element == ZERO ) {
                ++zeros.counter;
                zeros.location = idx;
                zeros.count = zeros.counter;
                indices_.push_back( zeros );
            }

            if ( element == e && element == POS ) {
                ++ones.counter;
                ones.location = idx;
                ones.count = ones.counter;
                indices_.push_back( ones );
            }
            idx++;
        } // for each T in data_

        // Reset static counters
        negOnes.counter = 0;
        zeros.counter = 0;
        ones.counter = 0;

        // Now that we saved a record: find the nth occurance
        // This will not search the full vector unless it is last element
        // This has early termination. Also this vector should only be
        // a percentage of the original data vector's size in elements.
        for ( auto index : indices_ ) {
            if ( index.count == NthOccurrence) {
                // We found a match
                return index.location;
            } 
        }

        // Not Found
        return -1;
    }
};
```

---

```
int main() {

    // using the sample array or vector from User: Prune's answer!
    std::vector<char> vec{ -1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1 };


    RepititionSearch <char> search( vec );
    unsigned idx = search.getNthOccurrence( 3, 1 );

    std::cout << idx << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char q;
    std::cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// output:
10
```

The value of 10 is the correct answer as the 3<sup>rd</sup> occurrence of the value `1` is at location 10 in the original vector since vectors are `0` based. The vector of indices is only used as `book keeping` for faster search.

If you noticed I even made this a class template to accept any basic type `T` that'll be stored in `std::vector<T>` as long as `T` is comparable, or has operators defined for it.

AFAIK I do not think that there is any other searching method that is faster than this for the type of search that you are striving for, but don't quote me on it. However I think I can optimize this code a little more... just need some time to look at it closer.

---

This may appear to be a bit crazy but this does work: just a bit of fun playing around with the code

```
int main() {

    std::cout << 
    RepititionSearch<char>( std::vector<char>( { -1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1 } ) ).getNthOccurrence( 3, 1 ) 
              << std::endl;  
}
```

It can be done on a single line & printed to the console without creating an instance of class.

---

**- 2nd Build**

Now this may not necessarily make the algorithm faster, but this would clean up the code a bit for readability. Here I removed the typedefs, and just by using a single version of the `Index` struct in the 3 if statements you will see `duplicate` code so I decided to make a private helper function for that and this is how simple the algorithm looks for clear readability.

---

```
struct Index {
    unsigned location;
    unsigned count;
    static unsigned counter;

    Index() : location(0), count(0) {}
};
unsigned Index::counter = 0;

template<class T>
class RepitiionSearch {
public:
    const T NEG  { -1 };
    const T ZERO {  0 };
    const T POS  {  1 };

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;
    std::vector<Index> indices_;

public:
    explicit RepititionSearch( const std::vector<T>& data ) : data_( data ) 
        indices_.clear();            
    }

    unsigned getNthOccurrence( unsigned NthOccurrence, T element ) {
        if ( NthOccurrence < 0 || NthOccurrence >= data.size() ) {
            return -1;
        }

        indices_.clear(); 

        Index index;     
        unsigned i = 0;

        for ( auto e : data_ ) {
            if ( element == e && element == NEG ) {
                addIndex( index, i );
            }
            if ( element == e && element == ZERO ) {
                addIndex( index, i );
            }
            if ( element == e && element == POS ) {
                addIndex( index, i );
            }
            i++;
        }
        index.counter = 0;

        for ( auto idx : indices_ ) {
            if ( idx.count == NthOccurrence ) {
                return idx.location;
            }
        }

        return -1; 
    }

private:
    void addIndex( Index& index, unsigned inc ) {
        ++index.counter;
        index.location = inc;
        index.count = index.counter;
        indices_.push_back( index );
    }
};
```

---

**- 3rd Build**

And to make this completely generic to find any `Nth occurrence` of any element `T` the above can be simplified and reduced down to this: I also removed the static counter from `Index` and moved it to the private section of `RepititionSearch`, it just made more sense to place it there.

```
struct Index {
    unsigned location;
    unsigned count;
    Index() : location(0), count(0) {}
};

template<class T>
class RepititionSearch {    
private:
    static unsigned counter_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
    std::vector<Index> indices_;

public:
    explicit RepititionSearch( const std::vector<T>& data ) : data_( data ) {
        indices_.clear();
    }

    unsigned getNthOccurrence( unsigned NthOccurrence, T element ) {
        if ( NthOccurrence < 0 || NthOccurrence >= data_.size() ) {
            return -1;
        }
        indices_.clear();

        Index index;
        unsigned i = 0;

        for ( auto e : data_ ) {
            if ( element == e ) {
                addIndex( index, i );
            }
            i++;
        }
        counter_ = 0;

        for ( auto idx : indices_ ) {
            if ( idx.count == NthOccurrence ) {
                return idx.location;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

private:
    void addIndex( Index& index, unsigned inc ) {
        ++counter_;
        index.location = inc;
        index.count = counter_;
        indices_.push_back( index );
    }    
};

template<class T>
unsigned RepititionSearch<T>::counter_ = 0;
```

---

**- 4th Build**

I have also done this same algorithm above without the need or dependency of needing a vector just to hold index information. This version doesn't need the `Index` struct at all and doesn't need a helper function either. It looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class RepititionSearch {
private:
    static unsigned counter_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
public:
    explicit RepititionSearch( const std::vector<T>& data ) : data_( data ) {}

    unsigned getNthOcc( unsigned N, T element ) {
        if ( N < 0 || N >= data_.size() ) {
            return -1;
        }

        unsigned i = 0;
        for ( auto e : data_ ) {
            if ( element == e ) {
                ++counter_;
                i++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }

            if ( counter_ == N ) {
                counter_ = 0;
                return i-1;
            }
        }

        counter_ = 0;

        return -1;
    }
};

template<class T>
unsigned RepititionSearch<T>::counter_ = 0;
```

---

Since we were able to remove the dependency of the secondary vector and removed the need for a helper function; we don't even need a class at all to hold the container; we can just write a function template that takes a vector and apply the same algorithm. Also there is no need for a static counter with this version.

---

**- 5th Build**

```
template<class T>
unsigned RepititionSearch( const std::vector<T>& data, unsigned N, T element ) {    

    if ( data.empty() || N < 0 || N >= data.size() ) {
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned counter = 0;
    unsigned i = 0;

    for ( auto e : data ) {
        if ( element == e ) {
            ++counter;
            i++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }

        if ( counter == N ) {
            return i - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

Yes this is a lot to take in; but these are the steps that are involved in the process of writing and designing an algorithm and refining it down to simpler code. As you have seen I have refined this code about 5 times. I went from using a `struct`, a `class`, `typedefs`, and a `static member` with multiple stored containers, to removing the `typedefs` and putting the repeatable code into a helper function, to removing the dependency of a secondary container & the helper function, down to not even needing a class at all and just creating a function that does what it is supposed to do.

You can apply a similar approach to these steps into building a function that does what you want or need it to do. You can use the same process to write a function that will do a binary search, hash table, etc.

Comment: Why do you say that binary tree is necessary for binary search?
Std library contains build-in function for binary seach on any sorted container with forward iterator:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/

Comment: @MarekWawrzos I'll have to go back and read my post; I'm still in the process of editing.

Comment: @MarekWawrzos Thank you for the heads up; I had multiple thoughts at different times while writing this answer. I've edited it dozens of times. I failed to go back and to read the actual sentences instead of just the "code refining". Thumbs up! If you see anything else that may seem inaccurate do not hesitate to give me a hint or clue.

Comment: @MarekWawrzos I remember now about the `binary search` statement; I never completed my train of thought earlier for I was called away from my keyboard several times... yes there is binary search for vectors, but they expect the criteria to be already sorted. In the OP's case; his containers are not sorted, and I believe they needed to maintain their current order... or at least that is what I was assuming or understanding from their question and others' comments.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I expect this suffers from being too long for the pertinent ideas.  After final editing, this would make a lovely blog post in a software development tutorial.  However, to make it a good SO answer, it should serve the question much more directly: more about the *solution* than about the process.

Comment: @Prune True, however the OP did explicitly state they were unsure of how to approach the modeling process of designing an algorithm... And the algorithm I displayed here with its 4-5 iterations of refinement does solve their problem.

Comment: @Prune I took your advice and I posted a 2nd answer which would be the one for the OP to decide to accept or not; and referred to this answer here as only a `reference answer` if they are interested in the breakdown process of how to design or model such an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The OP stated that the ordered structure is important and that the `vector` or `array` is `unsorted`. To the best of my knowledge there is no faster search algorithm than linear for unsorted data. Here are a few links for references:

- [gamedev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/381428-whats-the-fastest-search-algorithm/)
- [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-faster-way-to-search-in-an-unsorted-array-than-O-n)
- [discuss.codechef.com](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/87321/fastest-search-algorithm-for-unsorted-array)
- [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664029)

With the above links for references; this should be enough evidence to conclude that if the data in the `array` or `vector` is unsorted and must maintain its structure, then there is but no choice to use linear iteration, it may be possible to use a hashing technique, but that can still be tricky, using binary search will only work on `sorted` data in most cases.

---

*- Here is a good linear algorithm to find the `Nth` occurrence of `T` in `data`.*

To solve your problem of finding the `Nth` occurrence of element `T` in a given `unsorted` `array`, `vector` or `container` you can use this simple function template:

- It takes 3 parameters:

  - a const reference to the container that is populated with data
  - a const unsigned value `N` where `N` is the `Nth` occurrence.
  - and a const template type `T` that you are searching for.
- It returns an unsigned value for the index location within the container
  of the `Nth` occurrence of element `T`

---

```
template<class T>
unsigned RepititionSearch( const std::vector<T>& data, const unsigned N, const T element ) {    

    if ( data.empty() || N < 0 || N >= data.size() ) {
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned counter = 0;
    unsigned i = 0;

    for ( auto e : data ) {
        if ( element == e ) {
            ++counter;
            i++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }

        if ( counter == N ) {
            return i - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

**Break down of the algorithm**

> - It first does some sanity checks:
>
>   - It checks to see if the container is empty
>   - It checks the value `N` to see if it is within bounds of `[0,container.size())`
>   - If any of these fail, it returns `-1`; in production code this might throw
>       an exception or an error
> - We then have a need for 2 incrementing counters:
>
>   - 1 for the current index location
>   - 1 for the number of occurrences of element `T`
> - We then use a simplified for loop using `c++11` or higher
>
>   - We go through each `e` in `data`
>   - We check to see if the `element` passed into the function is `equal to`
>       the current `e` in `data`
>   - If the check passes or is true we then `pre-increment` `counter` and
>       `post-increment` `i` otherwise we only want to `post-increment` `i`
>   - After incrementing the counters we then check to see if the current
>       `counter` is equal to the `Nth` value passed into the function
>   - If the check passes we return the value of `i-1` since containers are `0` based
>   - If the check fails here we then continue to the next iteration of the loop and repeat the process
> - If after all `e` in `data` has been checked and there are no occurrences
>      of `T == e` or `N != counter` then we leave the for loop and the function
>      returns a `-1`; in production code this might throw an exception or return an error.

---

The worst case scenario here is either there are no finds, or the `Nth` occurrence of `T` happens to be the very last `e` in `data` where this will yield `O(N)` which is linear, and for basic containers this should be efficient enough. If the containers have `array indexing` capabilities their item access should be `O(1)` constant if you know which index location you want.

---

Note: This would be the answer that I feel should solve the problem, if you are interested in a breakdown of how the design process of designing or modeling such an algorithm works you can refer to my `reference answer` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199862/1757805)

AFAIK I do not think there is a `better` way to do this with `unsorted array data`, but don't quote me on it.

Comment: The question was asking for a better way. You merely rewrote iteration.

Comment: @KennyOstrom For unsorted array data; I don't think there is a better way.